SELECT AS STRUCT, SOA
I know there is the SELECT AS STRUCT construction in BigQuery, but wouldn't the following do the exact same thing? Or does the AS STRUCT construction give any additional benefits?
-- SELECT AS STRUCT 1 a, 2 b
SELECT _ FROM (SELECT 1 a, 2 b) _ 

-- SOA
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT _ FROM (SELECT 1 a, 2 b UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3) _)


Hi @David542, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

In an ARRAY subquery, The SELECT list must have exactly one column of any type, which defines the element type of the array returned by the array subquery. If not, an error is returned.
But when the subquery is written with SELECT AS STRUCT, the SELECT list can include multiple columns, and the value returned by the array subquery is an ARRAY of the constructed STRUCTs.
We can't select multiple columns without using SELECT AS since it returns an error.
You can refer to this documentation for example and detailed explanation.

Even though both queries will return the same results, there are other benefits to use SELECT AS STRUCT.
Performance: In some cases, SELECT AS STRUCT can be more efficient as it directly tells BigQuery to create a struct. The subquery method might add unnecessary complexity and overhead.
Nested Structs:
SELECT AS STRUCT is more straightforward and readable when dealing with nested structs or arrays of structs.
Readability and Maintenance:
Code readability and maintainability are improved with SELECT AS STRUCT. It clearly indicates the intention to create a struct, making it easier for others (or yourself in the future) to understand the query.

SELECT AS STRUCT and SELECT ARRAY do very different things.
SELECT AS STRUCT ... affects columns, merging all columns into a single STRUCT. It typically only changes metadata about the result, presenting all the columns as a single value wrapped in the struct.
SELECT ARRAY ... affects rows, merging all rows returned by subquery into a single array value. A single array value is very different from a table, that one would get otherwise. E.g. it is limited to 100MB overall size, cannot be split amount partitions and clustering, etc.
To demonstrate:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM (SELECT 1 a, 2 b UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3))

This returns 2.
But if we do SELECT ARRAY:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM (SELECT 1 a, 2 b UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3)))

We get 1.
There is some interaction between two constructs: an array can only contain a single column, so the second query that uses SELECT ARRAY also needs SELECT AS STRUCT. In the first query AS STRUCT is optional.
